# What is required to develop using Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have just paid the $19 fee to start using Unreal Engine 4 and have been playing around with the interface for a few hours now.

I've decided that it's finally time to start writing some code, but I'm worried I may not be equipped to do so.

My machine is 5 or 6 years old and running Windows Vista, I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional installed. I've noticed that Unreal seems to only support Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 (Professional only, not Express).

Do I need Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 to write code for Unreal 4? I looked around for Visual Studio 2012 but it doesn't seem to support Vista, and I don't really want to drop $399.99 on 2013 unless there is no other option.

I'm really excited to start work on a game with Unreal Engine 4, but can I? If I should be asking this question somewhere else please let me know and I will gladly move it.

Comment: As of this week, Unreal Engine 4 became free. Praise the sun!

Comment: Yes it is, I would still happily pay for it though, but good on them.

Answer (score 3):

The system requirements are listed [here](https://www.unrealengine.com/register):

> #### System Requirements
>
> Desktop PC or Mac
>
> - Windows 7 64-bit or Mac OS X 10.9.2 or later
> - Quad-core Intel or AMD processor, 2.5 GHz or faster
> - NVIDIA GeForce 470 GTX or AMD Radeon 6870 HD series card or higher
> - 8 GB RAM

So it would seem that Windows Vista simply isn't supported at all. Presumably, this means Epic cannot guarantee that the engine, if it happens to run, or any version of VS that happens to work on Windows Vista is supported either. Unfortunately, you may be out of luck.

Comment: OK thanks, but why is it working on my machine? I'm able to run the sample project and interact with the interface. When installations occur aren't the system specs and operating system checked?

Comment: @PaulG: You mean the engine? Perhaps UE4 games need to be able to run on Vista, but development isn't supported.

Comment: @BoldClock Unreal Editor

Comment: Maybe you should ask them to clarify. It looks like they're trying not to make any distinction between the engine and the UDK with the new engine, which makes it potentially confusing. But maybe that's because I don't actually work with Unreal Engine.

Comment: Well thanks for the help, I might have to get a new machine, my wife won't be happy about that but I will.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up buying a copy of Windows 7 and downloading a student version of Visual Studio 2013 from DreamSpark.

This seems to be the only comfortable way to develop using Unreal Engine 4 as they support Visual Studio 2013 very well, including intellisense. It seems that UE4 and VS2013 go hand in hand.

My computer ended up being just too slow in the end though, where it would take almost 2 minutes for VS2013 to fire up, and over 4 hours to compile the UE4 source code.

A friend of mine ended up bringing over a beast of a machine and we set up our game dev environment on it, including UE4 and VS2013, and I managed to compile the UE4 source on it in about 20 minutes.

In the end, the answer is NO, my old machine as it was could not run the tools necessary to develop using UE4 "comfortably".

Ideally you would have a beast of a machine running 64 bit Windows 7 or higher, and VS2013 seems like a natural fit.

PS: I feel bad answering my own question.

Comment: Paul, I develop in it now with Visual Studio Community edition (it's free), in my notebook, with a discrete video card. It's not a beef computer. What are your specs? Maybe we can improve perfomance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> "Do I need Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 to write code for Unreal 4? I looked around for Visual Studio 2012 but it doesn't seem to support Vista, and I don't really want to drop $399.99 on 2013 unless there is no other option."

You don't need to have vs2012 or 2013, generally you will just need the redistributables (I think this is what they are called) which are free to download and should automatically download when you install UE4.

Answer (score 0):

You can start things off by using their graphical script builder Blueprints. The amount of things that you can accomplish with Blueprints is fairly amazing and they are actively adding in new features literally by the day. My opinion is that it should keep you satiated until you decide whether to get VS or not.